# Programmatically Checking DevExpress CheckedComboBoxEdit Items

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a CheckedComboBoxEdit that's bound to a TableAdapter that populates it with a list of items.

I have a separate query that returns a dataset that lists the items that need to be checked.

I need to iterate through the CheckedComboBoxEdit items to check them as needed.

How can I make the CheckedComboBoxEdit reflect the data from the query which returns a list of items that need to be checked?

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010 with DevExpress 10.2.9.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and any other solutions to this issue would be great too.

Comment: Do you know the checkbox names before hand? Or are they dynamic? If you know them, then write method that checks the checked sate of each checkbox then do something..

Comment: @Anon : The CheckedComboBox item names are dynamic. I have a dataset that lists all the items from the CheckedComboBox that need to be checked. I'm not sure how and when to apply it. Which event should I use to do that with?

Comment: What is a CheckedComboBox? Is this a custom control you have made? You said the values are stored in your dataset, then why not just loop through the dataset looking for your condition that sets the checkbox to checked?

Comment: @Anon : CheckedComboBoxEdit http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic

Comment: @banging : Added a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items state of the CheckedComboBoxEdit tied to its EditValue. You can check items by setting an appropriate editor value: a list of values (each item has the value and display text) delimited with a separator sign. The separator sign is specified via the RepositoryItemCheckedComboBox.SeparatorChar property.

Comment: Note: Default value for the `SeparatorChar` is a comma. https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit_SeparatorChartopic

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to

```
checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SeparatorChar = ';';
// Set the edit value, assuming you have items named "one",and "two"
checkedComboBoxEdit1.SetEditValue("one; two");
```

[Here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdit_SetEditValuetopic) is the complete example

Answer (score 1):

Short code snippet.

```
string str = "first;second";
string[] array = str.Split(';');
char separator = checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SeparatorChar;
string result = string.Empty; 
foreach (var element in array){
   result += element + separator;
}

checkedComboBoxEdit1.SetEditValue(result);
```